# Can someone please point out the flaw in my proof?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a proper map.Show that $f$ takes discrete sets to discrete sets.

**Proof**:Let $A$ be discrete in $X$ and let $K$ be compact in $Y$ then $f(A) \cap K=f(A \cap f^{-1}(K))$,is finite since $A \cap f^{-1}(K)$ is finite.Hence $f(A)$ is discrete

But @Alex Ravsky here [Does proper map $f$ take discrete sets to discrete sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296450/does-proper-map-f-take-discrete-sets-to-discrete-sets) gave  a counter example. So can Someone please point out the flaw in my proof?

Comment: @Ken that question was also asked by me.I request you to read my question again

Comment: Yes, I understand that. My question is to the broader community: do these things get shuffled into one post or are multiple questions tied to the same sequence of thought allowed.

Comment: My understanding is this question is just pointing out another question of his, a sort of "bump" but a well disguised one.

Comment: @Learner, Why $f(A)\cap K=f(A\cap f^{-1}(K))?$  Is $f$ injective?

Answer (score 1):

$K$ does not necessarily equal $f(f^{-1}(K))$.